Powershell initialize strings in a loop
$formFields = @("UserSurname","UserFirstName")

 foreach ( $field in $formFields ) {

    $($field+"Label") = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $($field+"Label").Width = 25
}

I'm trying to initialize a bunch of form items from a string of components. I just don't understand how to initialize a variable from another value in a loop. I have tried many things but I think this code best illustrates what I am trying to do.
Just can't seem to construct the right values in the loop

You can use the Set-Variable cmdlet for this:
$formFields = @("UserSurname","UserFirstName")

foreach ( $field in $formFields ) {
    $label = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Width = 25
    Set-Variable -Name "${field}Label" -Value $label
}

Although you might want to consider using a hashtable or other dictionary type instead:
$formFields = @("UserSurname","UserFirstName")
$formFieldLabels = @{}
foreach ( $field in $formFields ) {
    $label = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Width = 25
    $formFieldLabels[$field] = $label
}

Now you can refer to the label instance with $formFieldLabels["UserSurname"]
